# Set value for variable in Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito

In one of my tests, I need to evaluate a logical expression. For example `(A&&B)||C` . I am using Mockito for testing and the sample is shown below

```java
@Test
public void test() {
 Item item = new Item();
    item.setUid("fc_uf_wzdf_0018");
    item.setDeviceName("test");
    item.setDeviceId("devID");
    Aggregation aggregation =
        new Aggregation("1", "(fc_uf_wzdf_0021 && fc_uf_wzdf_0025)||fc_uf_wzdf_0027)");
    List<Aggregation> aggregationList = new ArrayList<Aggregation>();
    aggregationList.add(aggregation);
    item.setAggregation(aggregationList);
    Runner underTest =
        new Runner(applicationEventPublisher, applicationCacheHandler, item);
    underTest.run();
}
```

In the above chunk of code, this item which I have defined here, is evaluating an expression defined in aggregation. To test it. I need to pass values for individual ID`s. Any suggestion, please?

PS: first time with Mockito.

Comment: Can you also add the source code for your class under test? Otherwise it's hard to give suggestions on what and how to mock.